# Use of autoreleased objects in C++ code

Tags: objective-c, opengl, objective-c++, autorelease

I'm currently writing code to get an OpenGL texture from an NSView. The code is mostly Apple sample code. However, I need to use it in a C++ class and I have problems with leaking objects.

Here's the interesting part of the code:

```
GLuint CPlusPlusClass::openGLTexFromNSView(NSView* theView)
{
    GLuint texName = 0x0;

    @autoreleasepool // 1
    {  // 1
        NSBitmapImageRep* bitmap = [theView bitmapImageRepForCachingDisplayInRect:[theView visibleRect]];

        int samplesPerPixel = 0;
        [theView cacheDisplayInRect:[theView visibleRect] toBitmapImageRep:bitmap];

        samplesPerPixel = (int)[bitmap samplesPerPixel];

        glPixelStorei(GL_UNPACK_ROW_LENGTH, (int)([bitmap bytesPerRow]/samplesPerPixel));
        glPixelStorei (GL_UNPACK_ALIGNMENT, 1);

        glGenTextures (1, &texName);

        glBindTexture (GL_TEXTURE_RECTANGLE_ARB, texName);
        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_RECTANGLE_ARB, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);

        if(![bitmap isPlanar] && (samplesPerPixel == 3 || samplesPerPixel == 4))
        {
            glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_RECTANGLE_ARB, 0,
                         samplesPerPixel == 4 ? GL_RGBA8 : GL_RGB8,
                         (int)[bitmap pixelsWide], (int)[bitmap pixelsHigh],
                         0, samplesPerPixel == 4 ? GL_RGBA : GL_RGB,
                         GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, [bitmap bitmapData]);
        }
    } // 1
    return texName;
}
```

When I'm drawing my view to an OpenGL context and check the memory footprint of the app in Activity Monitor I see the number increasing by about 4 MB every time Activity Monitor's view refreshes. By adding the `@autoreleasepool` block indicated by `//1` in the code, I could bring it down to about 2 MB per refresh cycle. Still, it's constantly increasing.

What's the correct way of freeing autoreleased objects from C++?

Answer (score 4):

That isn't `C++`, it is `Objective-C++`.

Which indirectly answers the question;  you manage Objective-C objects in Objective-C++ exactly as you would in straight Objective-C.

For hand rolled threads, you'll need to manage autorelease pools manually.  Make sure there is a pool in place prior to the first call to Objective-C in the thread and make sure it is drained just prior to the thread's exit.   If the thread is long lived, then you'll want to create and drain autorelease pools periodically (just as they are in run loops automatically).

Comment: But that's what I thought I did with the `@autoreleasepool` block. I exchanged `@autoreleasepool` with `[[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init]` and a `[pool drain]` at the end of the function with the same results. BTW, this is called from a hardware callback thread every video frame.

Comment: It was a bit of general answer given the lack of additional code.  I had assumed that you were accreting Objective-C objects;  bad assumption!  My knowledge of the gl API is woefully lacking.

Answer (score 0):

It turned out that what I was doing with the `@autoreleasepool` was absolutely correct.

The functioned I outlined above is called about 50-60 times per second.
I found out that the increased memory load was produced by the repeated call of `glGenTextures`. It should be stored in a variable instead and not be overwritten every time.

I didn't consider that there was an issue on that end.
Thought it was autorelease pool related ...